# How to move from partition to another from (browse)button

Tags: partitioning

I have installed Ubuntu 15 one day ago as i am going to switch from windows. I have a little experience in dealing with Linux.

I have installed jdk and netbeans on my Ubuntu. I have pervious Java work at another partition.

As I am trying to open those projects using (browse) button on netbeans. I just cannot get out from the Ubuntu partition.

I have solved this problem partially by making a shortcut at home folder to access that partition.

I am looking for a better solution for this case and the similars.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure your Windows partition is mounted.

You can use `lsblk -f` to find the mount locations.

Typically the mounted partitions are located at `/media/<USER>/<LABEL>`

If the NTFS partition is automatically [mounted during boot](http://www.linuxdeveloper.space/mount-ntfs-partition-on-boot/) then use `cat /etc/fstab` find its mount point.

[image]